# as3 looping MC from class not adding X propertity correctly

Tags: actionscript-3, class, loops, movieclip

I have a simple loop that creates a movieClip from a class in my library. It's adding the first part of the equation to the x property but not the plus 50. HOWEVER, it is adding the +50 but only to the first item in the loop. What am I doing wrong here?

```
var flagButton:MovieClip;

function displayFlagButtons()
{

    for( var i = 0; pages.length > i; i++)
    {

        flagButton = new roundButton();

            // The line below is giving me issues in adding 50 to each movieClip
            flagButton.x = (flagButton.width * i) + 50; 
            // Again, above code adds 50 to 1st item only


        addChild(flagButton);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you mean :

```
flagButton.x = (flagButton.width + 50) * i;
```

Comment: That did it but it only added 50 to all following and not the first. To add 50 to the first and all I had to use this code: flagButton.x = (flagButton.width + 50) * i + 50; - Why did yours work and not mine? What's with the math on this? I don't understand it.

Comment: Let's say `width` is `100` so the part inside brackets will be `150`. And `i` goes from 0 to x so the values `x` will get will be 0,150,300 which means the objects will be spaced horizontally with 50px between them. The code you had didn't work because it was multiplying `width` by `i` and then adding a constant `50`

Comment: Perhaps you have some idea on this one too. This is the final output for the issue. Its related but I just made a separate post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347810/as3-accessing-children-from-dynamicly-added-moiveclip