# as3 accessing Children from dynamicly added moiveclip

Tags: actionscript-3, class, loops, dynamic, children

I am adding moiveClips and putting their position accordingly. I am placing all the dynamically added clips in one new movie clip and then centering that on stage.  As a test, I see I can control the alpha in the main container but I can not access the children.  How can I assess each flagButton separately? There would be several in this loop example below.

```
var flagButton:MovieClip;
var flagArray:Array = new Array;
var flagDisplayButtons:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
function displayFlagButtons()
{




for( var i = 0; flagArray.length > i; i++)
{
    var flagButton:MovieClip = new roundButton();
    flagButton.x = (flagButton.width + 10) * i;
    flagButton.y = stage.stageHeight - flagButton.height;
    addChild(flagButton);

    flagDisplayButtons.addChild(flagButton);
}
addChild(flagDisplayButtons);

// Works
flagDisplayButtons.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - flagDisplayButtons.width/2;

// Does not see flagButton
flagDisplayButtons.flagButton.alpha = .5;
}
```

**GETS ERROR:**
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example code, you have created a bunch of button instances, and one by one you have added them to the display list of flagDisplayButtons. They are on that display list in the order that you placed them.

first instance is at index 0

second instance is at index 1

third instance is at index 2

and so on.

So if you want to access the third button you added, you could do this :

```
var flagButton:RoundButton = flagDisplayButtons.getChildAt(2) as RoundButton;
```

Now that you have created variable to reference that button, you can do any of these :

```
flagButton.alpha = .5;
flagButton.x = 100;
flagButton.y = 200;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed because I needed to access a mc inside the class called tButton. It works now with your var example. flagButton.tButton.visible = true. Awesome! :)

Comment: Actually I stand corrected. This won't work now. I changed a mc name in the roundButton class and now am trying to make a child of the flagButton visible but its not working. It is seeing the flagButton and I can control it's alpha but not access the child. Is this because I updated the mc?

Comment: I'd have to see your RoundButton class. You have to realize that if it's not a public property/method, it's not accessible in an instance of that class. That's likely the problem.

Comment: Also, if something doesn't work now, it's really a new question. It sounds like you now have an issue with understanding public/private methods/properties of a class. Best not to start up new topics inside this question.

Comment: The roundButton class is created via the Export in Actionscript via an adobe Box. I don't touch the code. What I am trying to do is make buttons like on iPhone at bottom. One will highlight according to the page its on. It will display according to a swipe. I need to access all of them. but the content is dynamic so I need it to be in an array where I can say ... If page 1 then flagButton.myHighlight.visible  = true; As an example. So how do I get all these in an array or access them dynamically and not hard coded?

Comment: is myHighlight a child of the RoundButton symbol in your IDE ? If so, and it has the instance name myHighlight, it will be accessible. But, again, this is a completely different topic. if you email me at prototype.in.training@gmail.com I can help you out via chat with some basic concepts that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getChildAt` or `getChildByName` to get the children of a `DisplayObjectContainer`

IE:

```
flagDisplayButtons.getChildAt(0).alpha = 0.5;
```

Comment: This helped me get access as I requested. Thank you. I did need another level and the code above help me get to that level. Thank you so much for your wisdom in coding in as3 :)